# SyntaxError: invalid syntax error using xpath with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am writing a simple code where I needed to extract the contents of a html tag which was `<span>`. I've used the xpath to do it.
Here's the error

```
File "C:\Users\BRS\Desktop\AccountChef\wattpad acc maker - Copy.py", line 41
    emailentry = wd.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id='email']//span)).getText();
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Since it's a syntax error, I don't think I need to give whole code.
Please tell what i did wrong

Comment: A string must be in quotation marks.

Comment: As @DYZ mentioned, you need to wrap the parameter to `By.xpath` in quotes: `"//*[@id='email']//span"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is a mixup of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [java](/questions/tagged/java) language binding syntax.

- If you are using *Python* you need to use `find_element_by_xpath()` and *text* attribute as follows:

  ```
  emailentry = wd.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='email']//span").text
  ```
- If you are using *Java* you need to use `findElement()` and `getText()` method as follows:

  ```
  String emailentry = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']//span")).getText();
  ```

Comment: @muzaafnameerfirdausi Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.